# Do OpenJPA and/or Hibernate support variable relationships like EclipseLink does?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, openjpa

I am using Felix OSGi framework, where EclipseLink dynamic weaving isn't supported, so I'd prefer to use OpenJPA (or possibly Hibernate). However, one feature I need in a couple of places is [variable one-to-many relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Variable_and_Heterogeneous_Relationships), where one entity refers to a collection of entities of different classes (which share the same superclass). Is this supported by other providers? The link only mentions EclipseLink, but it may not be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

[DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1) (and JDO) supports relations using interfaces, abstract classes etc, since that is part of the JDO spec (but not the JPA spec).

Don't expect the wikibooks page(s) to reflect what other implementations provide since it was written AFAIK by Oracle members who, naturally, will include what they know about. The pages are very good for general spec-based JPA info, but you should always look at the docs for the individual implementations for details of what they provide as vendor extensions. The pages also don't make it always so clear what is and isn't part of the spec or a vendor extension.

Comment: "Don't expect the wikibooks page(s) to reflect what other implementations provide since it was written AFAIK by Oracle members who, naturally, will include what they know about." Yes, that was the other reason I thought it could be missing this (it does mention some extensions provided by OpenJPA and Hibernate, but much more rarely).